# Prove that for all real numbers $x,y$ and $z$ that $x^2+y^2+1 \geq x+xy$.

Tags: inequality

> Prove that for all real numbers $x,y$ and $z$ that $x^2+y^2+1 \geq x+xy$.

It seems like I should apply AM-GM here, but I don't see how it helps.

Comment: how is $z$ related to this problem

Comment: What is the point of $z$?

Comment: @JacobWillis, in five days you have asked 12 questions, but have accepted a single answer. This kind of behaviour is discouraged here. It is normal not to accept answers only if they are of poor quality, but from what I have seen, you have received some very good ones. Please review your questions and, where the given answers helped you solve your problem, think about accepting them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have:
$$
\frac{x^2+1}{2}≥|x| \\
\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}≥|xy| \\
\frac{y^2+1}{2}≥|y|
$$
By AM_GM. Thus, adding yields:
$$
x^2+y^2+1≥|xy|+|x|+|y|≥xy+x
$$

Answer (score 4):

We have a stronger inequality: $$x^2+y^2+1-x-xy=\frac34\left(x-\frac23\right)^2+\left(\frac12x-y\right)^2+\frac23\geq\frac23\,.$$  The equality holds iff $x=\frac23$, $y=\frac13$, and $z$ is an arbitrary object, whatever it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 3):

No need for the AM-GM inequality here: rewrite this as $$\frac {x^2} 2 - x + \frac 1 2 + \frac {x^2} 2 - xy + \frac {y^2} 2 + \frac {y^2} 2 + \frac 1 2 \ge 0$$ which is trivially true, because the left-hand side is a sum of clearly positive numbers: $$\left( \frac x {\sqrt 2} - \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \right) ^2 + \left( \frac x {\sqrt 2} - \frac y {\sqrt 2} \right) ^2 + \frac {y^2} 2 + \frac 1 2 .$$

Answer (score 0):

If  $x^2+y^2+1-x-x y +d^2=0$ then $x^2+x(-1-y)+(y^2+1+d^2)=0$ which, seen as a quadratic equation in $x$, must have a non-negative discriminant. That is $(1+y)^2-4(y^2+1+d^2)\geq 0$. This is easily seen to be impossible even for $d=0$.